# How to resolve Django tutorial migration error?

Tags: django

I'm using this tutorial:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/
```

vim mysite/settings.py

```
`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)`
```

vim polls/models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
        choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.choice_text
        def was_published_recently(self):
                return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

`

after using all the code from the tutorial I encountered this error:

> python manage.py makemigrations

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'choice_text' to choice without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

 1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Select `2`. then `""` enough. Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988552/

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually this is not an error. Django is telling you that it needs a default value for `choice_text` to apply in the current rows stored in the database. Seems that you created the database table (probably with `syncdb`), added some data and now you made the `choice_text` field mandatory. So Django must fill empty instances of `choice_text` in the database with the new default value you are being asked. Make sense?

Just choose option `1)` and enter a value to apply in `choice_text` for all the current rows in the database.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't put any data in the database.

I only typed this codes:

    python manage.py shell